# Group by get first row without using join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table products:

```
ProductID ProductCode SupplierID
   1        WATCH         1
   2        WATCH         5
```

I want to group by product code:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductCode, SupplierID 
FROM products 
GROUP BY ProductCode 
ORDER BY SupplierID DESC
```

I want to display the last supplier id which is **5** with no where conditions, no join and no limit by 1.

Something like the output below.

```
ProductID ProductCode SupplierID
   2        WATCH         5
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

```
**Answered by Devon which is called as Noncorrelated Subquery**

SELECT ProductID, ProductCode, SupplierID 
FROM products 
WHERE SupplierID = (SELECT SupplierID FROM products ORDER BY SupplierID DESC LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY ProductCode 
ORDER BY SupplierID DESC
```

Comment: maybe you can use limit?

Comment: Why don't you want to use where or limit?

Comment: @RonaldAlexanderKailola - he mentioned no limit

Comment: i m sorry not note it

Comment: No, it's not possible.

You can't just filter (WHERE) or limit (LIMIT) your results without using proper SQL statements. :)

Comment: Why no where conditions, no join and no limit by 1? Don't push yourself too hard.

Comment: @Shudmeyer, if you should must update the `table and result details` its problem only they are all of them confusing,....

Comment: @jmail Devon already answer the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDO, you can run fetch() on the query to get the first row.  Or you can run mysqli_fetch_array() for mysqli api, but I don't see why you wouldn't want to use limit if you're only trying to get one row.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('..');
$firstrow = $stmt->fetch();
```

SQL Query to obtain product codes from last supplier:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductCode FROM products WHERE SupplierID = (SELECT SupplierID FROM products ORDER BY SupplierID DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: The code uses foreach() from php if i used this only one will be displayed. There are plenty of product codes on the table with different supplier id

Comment: So you're trying to obtain product codes from the last supplier?

Comment: Glad I could help.  This is called a noncorrelated subquery.  When you run an independent query and use it as a comparison for your main query.  There are many ways you can do this, you can also use a correlated query which is dependent on your main query.  Read up on them for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited the questions and write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductCode, MAX(SupplierID) 
FROM products 
GROUP BY ProductCode
```

**Note:**
The ProductID column value will be fuzzy i.e can be 1 or 2

Comment: why can't use max(ProductID)?

Comment: consider an additional row in table posted in question with productid=3 and supplierId=4 ..

Comment: MAX() only works on a single field not the entire row.

Comment: in your question you mentioned: "I want to display the last supplier id which is 5 with no where conditions, no join and no limit by 1."
not mentioning that you also want max productID

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible,  Use max() function for supplierID field and then group by the ProductCode.

Thanks

Comment: MAX() only works on a single field not the entire row.